# I want to run multiple variables in a for loop in tandem and i want to take the sum of each iteration of x and y

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, simultaneous

I want to run multiple variables in a for loop together and I want to capture the values of all the variables at each iteration and sum them up. I'm going to take an example with two variables here:

```
          for a,b in (range(a),range(b)):
              print(a+b)
```

I'm totally new to this space and apologies if I'm not able to follow the standard practices of laying out a problem on this community.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) method:

```
for a, b in zip(range(a), range(b)):
    print(a + b)
```

---

Do note that iterating over a variable using the same name as the variable for the iteration variables will overwrite the original variable, like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [3, 2, 1]
for x, y in zip(x, y):
    print(x + y)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
4
4
4
3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to couple two (or any number of) lists together.

```
a = [0,1,2]
b = [1,2,4]

for i, j in zip(a,b):
    print(i+j)
```